# Material tree node with checkbox change mapping

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, treeview

I have this stackblitz : [Tree View](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xdflat)

The tree is not building as expected; I want to have something like :

```
Manager
   Sub liste
     Manager 1
     Manager 2
     Manager 3
```

Can you take a look and give some advices please ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const TREE_DATA = {
  idManager: 1,
  label: "Manager",
  descendants: 
    {
      idManager: 2,
      label: "Sub liste",
      descendants: [
        {
          idManager: 3,
          label: "Manager 1"
        },
        {
          idManager: 4,
          label: "Manager 2"
        },
        {
          idManager: 5,
          label: "Manager 3"
        }
      ]
    }
  
};
```

Change your TREE_DATA structure

Comment: What do you mean ? I can't change, this is the return from API